# Umbraco database connection reach max pool size

Tags: umbraco7

Currently using version 7.13.2 with MySQL database.

When the usage in production server is high (with alot of concurrent user), Umbraco tend to create alot of database connection to handle those job. Those connection is not close after used but sleep.

[image: Database Connection Example]

Umbraco would continue to create more database connection when necessary until it reach the database max pool size.

Is this the intention behaviour by Umbraco? Else, how could we configure this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After hundred hours of debugging, I finally found out the cause and the solution is easy.

This bug has nothing to do with Umbraco, it handles the connection perfectly. Umbraco using MySql Connector when connecting to MySql database. When the connection close, it is actually not close but instead, added to connection pool. Please refer to link below for more information.

[MySql Connection not closing using .net MySql Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436920/mysql-connection-not-closing-using-net-mysql-connector)

The solution as suggested from the link, just adding "**Pooling=false**" as a string parameter into connection string. The connection string locate inside the web config.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk8ZW.png)